# Update table in mysql - delete old, insert new, update updated

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a mysql table displayed as an html table.  The user is able to update, insert and delete rows. I'd like to then update my mysql table once the save button is clicked.

My current method is to delete all rows and insert all new rows upon saving.  I have run into problems however when there is an error in my insert function, and I've already deleted everything.

I feel like this method is sloppy and causing unnecessary deletes.  It could potentially delete and insert 50 rows just to update one cell.

What is the proper method to update a table in mysql?

Edit:
My current working solution is this

- add a deleted column to the table, default value is 0
- create a unique index on the table for each cell in the row (except the ID)
- when the table is saved, update every row, set deleted = 1
- for each row in the table, insert into mysql, on duplicate set deleted = 0
- only show rows where deleted = 0

you could choose to delete the rows where deleted = 1 to clean it up, but I like to keep it as a backup.

Two problems arise with this solution:

- two identical rows are not allowed. mysql will just replace deleted = 0 if a duplicate is found
- if a cell in a row is changed, a new row will be created and won't simply update the old row.  this could be fixed, but I almost don't mind having an ability to 'undo' an edit.

Comment: SO isn't a code-me-please site. Please post what you have tried, what works, what doesn't work.

Comment: I understand. I'm looking for a theoretical answer rather than code, as I'm assuming this problem is quite common.

Comment: Okay, sorry for overreacting. I understand.

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas how to do it.

1.

If each row had an id, you could process the update directly. Just user->DB. If the change couldn't be applied, nothing is deleted.

> 1.| Jane | 20
>
> 2.| Philip | 30
>
> 3.| Lucas | 50

Generate query like update "2" replace his age from 30 to 20 and then, refresh window. The update will be processed and no deleting of all is needed. After refresh, new html table is written out with all changes.

2.

Keep using your method, but ensure in pararel table that update could be processed.

- If could, than show the table to user and and after his acceptation
  the paralel content of paralel table will be inserted into used one.
- If couldn't, write error and do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This week I had the same issue.
My decision was save the list data table in session variable. Later, insert this variable list on mysql. If this insert script get a exception, I rollback transaction to undo operation. But, no exception, all rows are deleted and session variable cleared.
I need improve this process too!

Comment: Thank you Fred. I wouldn't be angry if you could give me reputation...haha; Stepo

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on w3schools for "update".

U will need to do something along the lines of:

```
Update (tablename)
Set (columnname)='newvalue'
Where id='idYouWantToUpdate'
```

Updating is what u want to do. Not deleting everything and inserting everything again.

Comment: Not all rows will be only updates. The user is able to insert or delete rows into the HTML, as well as update cells.